# Which open source ethereum blockchain explorer is the best for private chain?

Tags: private-blockchain, explorers

I have got eth-net-stats deployed with my private ethereum chain, but apparently it's far from being a real blockchain explorer. 
Are there any good open source blockchain explorers for private ethereum exists?
Which one do you think is the best?
Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is two open source explorer projects, you could use in your private chain :

https://github.com/etherparty/explorer

https://github.com/maran/ethereum-blockchain-explorer

Comment: there is also https://github.com/trufflesuite/ganache

Comment: How to build the prod version for this?