# Exploring blockchain data from testrpc network

Tags: testrpc, ether-camp

What would be the best way to explore the blockchain content of the testing network? Ideally, is there a way to adapt https://live.ether.camp to track the local network? Alternatively, what could one use to inspect contents of the blockchain?

Comment: I think you're looking for this: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/9204/which-open-source-ethereum-blockchain-explorer-is-the-best-for-private-chain or this: https://github.com/gobitfly/etherchain-light

Comment: Shameless plug: http://quickblocks.io

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [Web3.js](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/), you can get chainblock content by command of `eth.getBlock(eth.blockNumber)`, and 
 access every attribute,

```
currentBlock = eth.getBlock(eth.blockNumber);
currentBlock.extraData;
currentBlock.transactions;
...
```

Comment: I am still a newbie, can you give me some more context please: where could I use the code you suggest? (or how to connect it to the blockchain). currently I am using truffle and its testing mechanism to experiment

Comment: please execute command `web3.eth.getBlock(0)` in truffle console, and `web3.eth.getBlock(0).attribute` will return attribute value.

Comment: great! The feature  of live.ether.camp that I am missing is inspecting what the transactions contain (is it contract creation; is it ether transfer, what exactly is transferred...) - but now I have a good place to start. If you know the place where this is explained, let me know